# How to save object into UserDefaults or keychain - Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I'm building a Shopify app, but first and foremost this is NOT a Shopify SDK question, it's regarding saving a customer token into userDefaults or Keychain. I've tried but most Keychain libraries I've tried only work with strings and I need to save the token as a whole which looks like this:

```
BUYCustomerToken(customerID: NSNumber!, accessToken: String!, expiry: Date!)
```

The shared client of the app to access the token looks like this:

```
BUYClient.sharedClient.customerToken
```

During sign up, user gets created successfully with token. Once I exit and go back into the app the

```
BUYClient.sharedClient.customerToken = ""
```

So my question is, how do I save this object into defaults or Keychain to recall later when entering app. I can't just save part of the token, like the accessToken which is just a String, I need the whole thing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save more than String types in UserDefaults, you have to store your token in multiple keys.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for
>   collections, a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

if you want to store the expiry date

```
let expiry = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "expiry") as? Date
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "expiry")
```

The CustomerID

```
let customerID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "customerID") as? NSNumber
UserDefaults.standard.set(1234, forKey: "customerID")
```

And for the token the same.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("YourAccessToken", forKey: "accessToken")

let accessToken = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("accessToken")
```

With this way, you just have to get them one by one, but you have all of them stored. I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you great answer! Figured it out right before I saw this and pretty much used your method! Thanks for the clear answer!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely **can** store the whole object in your `UserDefaults` or a Keychain, no problem. The trick is to make it conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, then use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to convert it to and from a `Data` object that can be stored. Don't worry, it sounds more complicated than it is.

**Conforming to NSCoding**

Presumably your `BUYCustomerToken` class is already a descendant of `NSObject`, so you're halfway there. You just need to add a couple of methods to allow your custom class to be encoded (turned into `Data`) and decoded automatically from an `NSCoder`. Specifically these are: `encode(with coder: NSCoder)` and `init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder)`. You then use the coder's various encode() and decode() functions to make these work. encode() and decode() work on any object that supports `NSCoding`, which includes `NSNumber`, `String`, and `Date`, so that makes your job here pretty easy. A finished codable class will look like this:

```
class BUYCustomerToken : NSObject, NSCoding {

    var customerID: NSNumber!
    var accessToken: String!
    var expiry: Date!

    override init() {
    }

    convenience init(customerID: NSNumber, accessToken: String, expiry: Date) {
        self.init()
        self.customerID = customerID
        self.accessToken = accessToken
        self.expiry = expiry
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        customerID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "customerID") as! NSNumber
        accessToken = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "accessToken") as! String
        expiry = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "expiry") as! Date
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(customerID, forKey: "customerID")
        aCoder.encode(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")
        aCoder.encode(expiry, forKey: "expiry")
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "ID: \(customerID!), Token: \"\(accessToken!)\", Expires: \(expiry!)"
    }
}
```

You can add in your own custom methods, of course. The `description` is not strictly necessary, but convenient for testing.

**Storing and Retrieving from UserDefaults**

Now that your class supports NSCoding, you can archive it and store it, then retrieve it.

To store it, you start by *archiving* it (converting it to a `Data` object) using `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject)`. This works because your class is `NSCoding` compliant. Once you get a `Data` object, you can store that in `UserDefaults` using `set(value, forKey)`.

When you want to retrieve it, you do it the other way: first fetch a `Data` object from `UserDefaults` using `data(forKey)`, then turn it back into an object using `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with)`, and finally cast it to your custom class.

Here's a bit of code that attempts to load a `BUYCustomerToken` from `UserDefaults`. If it succeeds, it prints the description; if it fails, it creates a new token and stores it. Put this code in the `viewDidLoad()` of your initial `UIViewController` to see it in action:

```
if let customerTokenData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "myToken") {
    let customerToken = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: customerTokenData) as! BUYCustomerToken
    print(customerToken)
} else {
    print("No token stored. Launch again to see token.")
    let customerToken = BUYCustomerToken(customerID: 999, accessToken: "some token", expiry: Date())
    let tokenData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: customerToken)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(tokenData, forKey: "myToken")
}
```

The first time you run it there's no stored token, so the output is:

> No token stored. Launch again to see token.

The second time, it will find the stored token and output its description:

> ID: 999, Token: "some token", Expires: 2017-05-31 21:27:25 +0000

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I used the previous answer, but definitely going to give this a shot and see how it works.

Comment: @ManuelAlonzo It's overkill if all you need to do is save a couple of strings. It's useful if you have more complex objects, or if you save multiple objects or save them to multiple places.

Comment: Yeah I guess Shopify only requires me to save the token which contains those 3 items. But I haven't gotten into cart structure yet which also has tokens if you want to recall saved carts, so this still might be useful!